# RelativeLayout in couple devices

Tags: java, android, layout

I am using `RelativeLayout` for put a textview on image for example, the problem that it is change the place on the screen for every device that i try(in the simulator).

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:layout_marginTop="-70dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/propfile" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_phone"
        android:textColor="@color/black" 
        android:layout_marginTop="337dp" android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"                 
        android:clickable="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why don't you use Relative/Linear-Layout background instead of ImageView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to put a `TextView` directly on `ImageView`? Like in this example http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html? If yes try `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the image a background of your relative layout, then just use a textview